# If default value from byte is 0 why it is writting spaces from an array of bytes

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, fileoutputstream

When an array is created all the elements are initialized to its default value. The default value of a byte is 0 but when I call to FileOutputStream's write method, it is printing spaces.

```
OutputStream w = new FileOutputStream(this.createFileFromRelativePArth(), true);
byte byteArray[] = new byte[50];
w.write(byteArray);
```

What is wrong with my premise?

Comment: It's writing null terminators (char 0), which are being displayed as spaces in whatever editor you are reading the file with.

Comment: nothing is wrong with your premise, so I imagine something else is happening that you are unaware of...

Comment: @Quirliom. Thanks, showing all special character in the Notepad++ I can see the NULL.